# Data Validation (Drop-Down List) in Excel into a whole column using VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I have managed to insert data validation (drop down list) into a single row in the column. However, I want to expand the data validation until the last row.

I can't find anywhere about data validation being expanded until the last row. just to clarify, it's not about changing the list of data validation, it's to have data validation in each row until the last row.

```
Sub datavalidation()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim neC As Range


Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
Set neC = tbl.DataBodyRange(1, 3)

With neC.Validation
.Delete
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
    AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Operator:=xlBetween, _
    Formula1:="=Table2"

.ErrorMessage = "Month"
.ErrorMessage = "Please select January until December from the list"

End With

End Sub
```

The code runs smoothly.
however, where do i add/change if i want data validation to apply to the next row till the last?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply validation lists to an entire range. Just expand the range to suit your needs.

The following code is very basic and serves as an example. For the example I chose col A through C to be filled with validation lists, from row 1 to the last filled row in column C.

```
Sub FillRangeWithValidationLists()
Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
Dim lrow As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet 'not recommended to use the active sheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheet1 'this would be a better method
lrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row 'last row in column C 
Set rng = ws.Range("A1:C" & lrow) 'populate the rng variable with range you want

With rng.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
    AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Operator:=xlBetween, _
    Formula1:="=Table2"
    .ErrorMessage = "Please select January until December from the list"
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Just change (ofc change Sheet1 for your sheet name)

```
 lastRow = sheets("Sheet1").cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row

 Formula1:="=Sheet1!A1:A"&lastRow
```